# FlatList not filling 100% height in react-native

Tags: react-native

I got a FlatList that occupies the 50% of the vertical space on the screen.
This FlatList has only a few items, and because of this, is not taking the entire space but only the half of it, and when I scroll up/down, it looks as if it has `overflow: hidden`.

I read [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4099) in the RN GitHub about it, they recommended using `flexGrow: 1` on the FlatList's `contentContainerStyle`, also the parent View with `flex: 1`. But is not working. Is this still working? They said to use it on ScrollViews, but isn't FlatList inherited from ScrollView or something like that?

This is my current structure:

```
render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                    numColumns={2}
                    style={ styles.cardContainer }
                    keyExtractor={ this._keyExtractor }
                    data={ this.state.listData }
                    renderItem={ this._renderItem }
                    >
                </FlatList>
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You actually want to put flex onto your `FlatList`. Currently you have it on your `contentContainerStyle`.

So `flex:1` on your `FlatList` will make it fill the rest of the container.

You'll want to adapt this to your solution depending on what you currently have in `styles.cardContainer`.

```
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <View style={{ height: Dimensions.get("window").height * 0.25 }} />
        <FlatList
          numColumns={2}
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          data={["1", "2", "3"]}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
        />
    </View>
```

Comment: I have flex: 1 already on both, cardContainer has `flex: 1 and flexDirection: 'column'`. A solution that i found for now is using Dimensions, but I don't know if i should. Looks kinda "dirty". So top container i did this: `height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.25` and then to the FlatList i put this `height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.75`... should I do it this way?? or is tooo ugly?

Comment: I think I'm miss understanding, could you post at least the styles of the top container? Are you trying to just get the `FlatList` to fill the parent `View`? Or something else?

Comment: I got a profileContainer on top to fill around 25% of screen, then the FlatList that will take the other 75%. The styles being applied to that profileContainer are the following: `height: Dimensions.get('window').height * 0.25, backgroundColor: 'white', borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth, borderBottomColor: '#c3c3c3'`

Comment: I've updated answer with a working example that I've just tested. `flex: 1` will be able to fill the rest of the space.

Comment: `flex: 1` will disable the scroll of long list

Answer (score 5):

Set the `contentContainerStyle` of the `FlatList` to `flexGrow: 1` will not block the scroll functionality on long list.

There might have issue with the old version, but latest works just fine.
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17944

Comment: No it does not, try a view above the flatlist and it goes crazy now.

Comment: You're right flexGlow: 1 will not block the scroll of flatlist

Answer (score 1):

Give the parent  a style of height: '100%' and use paddingBottom if you have a TabBar or something that's covering / not covering the Flatlist items correctly.

Eg:

```
<View style={{ paddingBottom: 60, height: '100%' }} >
   <FlatList ... />
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

To add onto this 2 years later, i had a justifyContent:center on my list container and that was what made the flex not fill the entire space. Otherwise flexGrow works.